# Why is my pointer to an array of structs that consists of an int array return garbage values when I create the array in a function and return it?

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct

**Update: Solved**

Source of errors was two things. First, the pointer after going through the first second while loop in `createRecords()` stayed at the end of the array and basically returned the end of the array. Secondly, the first while loop in `creatRecords()` had a conditional that prevented from gathering more lines as I was debugging and did not want to go through 7k lines of data. The array would have only 1 struct but when returned and checked in main, the for loop went over 10 times. Only one valid struct was valid and the rest was garbage.

[Source Files Here](https://github.com/Petetunze/Project2) Written in C for a project in university, I need to organize and query airplane route data from a CSV file for a user to be able to search information and data regarding a route. There are 6 columns of data to represent: `[month(as a number), origin, destination, airline, type, total number of passengers in that month for that route]`. The following is an example of a line of data:

```
6,TEB,RIX,LF,Passenger,2
```

Part of the assignment wants me to create a dynamically allocated array of structs. A struct for a line of data is written in `route-records.h` and is the following:

```
typedef struct RouteRecord_struct{
    char origin[4];
    char destin[4];
    char aaCode[4];
    int  passengersPerMonth[6];
}RouteRecord;
```

Note: You don't see `type` as every flight is of type passenger so type is meaningless in this case.

The assignment calls for a function `createRecords(FILE* fileIn)` that does the following:

- Goes throught the CVS file and counts the total amount of route records (lines).
- Create a dynmically allocated array of structs based on the number of lines.
- Each `RouteRecord` struct has an array of 6 integers where each index holds the number of passengers for 6 months. Set each element in the integer array to 0.
- Return the generated pointer to some pointer in `main`.

Where I have problems is `Set each element in the integer array to 0`. As of now I have successfully created the dynamic array in the `createRecords()` function. However, when I return the pointer back to main and print out an element to see if it worked, I get garbage values. But when I printed the values in the `createRecords()` function the value is set and equal to whatever value I set it as (3, 999, 75, etc).

The code is what I have below and the output follows.

`main.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "route-records.h"

int main(){

    FILE *fileIn;

    fileIn = fopen("data.csv", "r");

    if(fileIn == NULL){
        printf("Could not open file");
        return -1;
    }

    RouteRecord *records = createRecords(fileIn);

    // Print the first 10 integer arrays in the first 10 structs
    int i;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            
        int j;
        for(j = 0; j < 6; j++){
            printf("%d ", records->passengersPerMonth[j]);
        }
            
        printf("\n");
        records++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`route-records.c`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include "route-records.h"

RouteRecord* createRecords(FILE* fileIn){

    char currentLine[50];
    int lineCount = 0;
    int s = 0; 
    
    // Get the total amount of lines.
    while(fgets(currentLine, 50, fileIn)){
        
        if(s == 1){
            lineCount++;
        }
        else{
            s = 1;
        }
    }
    
    // Create the dynamic array
    RouteRecord* returnPtr = (RouteRecord*)malloc(sizeof(RouteRecord) * lineCount);
    
    // Set every index in the array of each struct to 0
    int i = 0;
    while(i < lineCount){
        
        int j;
        for(j = 0; j < 6; j++){
            records->passengersPerMonth[j] = 0;
        }
        
        i++;
        returnPtr++;
    }

    return returnPtr;
}
```

`route-records.h`

```
typedef struct RouteRecord_struct{

    char    originAirlineCode[4];
    char    destinAirlineCode[4];
    char    airlineCode[4];
    int     passengersPerMonth[6];
}RouteRecord;

RouteRecord* createRecords(FILE*);
```

`Output`

```
> ./output
12155696 12155696 12155696 12155696 12155696 12155696
1866670145 1866670145 1866670145 1866670145 1866670145 1866670145
1095516483 1095516483 1095516483 1095516483 1095516483 1095516483
7102819 7102819 7102819 7102819 7102819 7102819
1380270669 1380270669 1380270669 1380270669 1380270669 1380270669
1551069797 1551069797 1551069797 1551069797 1551069797 1551069797
1432107587 1432107587 1432107587 1432107587 1432107587 1432107587
1381319519 1381319519 1381319519 1381319519 1381319519 1381319519
1414422387 1414422387 1414422387 1414422387 1414422387 1414422387
1551066476 1551066476 1551066476 1551066476 1551066476 1551066476
```

I feel like I messed up returning the array in some way or creating the array. Printing them in main to make sure it returned correctly does not output to what I need. I've tried making a new pointer in main that points to the records array but that doesn't work. I have no idea what is causing this, and I don't want to have to redo all the code to make it work. Any ideas? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You're moving the `returnPtr` to the end of alloc'd memory in that `while()` loop. Use another temporary variable say `RouteRecord records = returnPtr;` after you `malloc()` it & before that loop. Then `return records;`

Comment: @SparKot So I added the line that you suggested. It sort of works but not 100%. The first line of values is what I need it to be/ set it equal to. However, the rest of the 9 lines are still garbage values.
```
0 0 0 0 0 0
7568176 0 7536976 0 1634878068 1551068777
1866670145 1853189485 544830569 1953064005 544108393 825372722
1095516483 1094996048 1128087892 1934974010 1551069797 1920099656
7102819 1330073420 1380275022 1028801878 1162107996 1330924371
1380270669 1598443359 1129271888 1330860869 826102610 1850671158
...
```

Comment: This program doesn't even compile. There are some glaringly misused identifiers. `records` is not in scope of `createRecords`. Where is `s` declared? `RouteRecords *records` should be `RouteRecord`. Please make sure to provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that produces the provided output.

Comment: @Oka I fixed some typos and deleted some unused stuff. I can upload the CVS file entirely if needed.

Comment: Did you read the page @Oka linked? Contemplate the word *"minimal".*

Comment: @Beta I uploaded the files to GitHub with just the needed files. It does compile on my end. Using MinGW.

Comment: @Oka I uploaded the source files in the main post. Has the main files with a small sample of data

Answer (score 0):

**Update**
SparKot's solution works. In my main code I have set a conditional that prevented from printing saving more line in the `while(fgets)` loops. I forgot I had this because there are 7k lines in the original CVS file and did not want to go though all 7k.